# Repaint() Method wiill not re-paint

Tags: java, swing

I cannot get my repaint method to work in my SimonPanel class. At first, I thought it was because I used paint() instead of paintComponent(), but that didn't seem to solve the problem. My

SimonShape.java(Holds the frame and changes the colors of the shape)

```
public class SimonShape extends JFrame implements KeyListener {



private int level = 1;

// speed of the light up sequence
private int lightUpSpd = 500;

// chooses random color based on numbers 0-3
private int random;

// keeps track of user inputs 
private int compCounter = 0;

ArrayList<Integer> comp = new ArrayList<Integer>();

SimonPanel simon = new SimonPanel();
//SimonLabel keyLabel = new SimonLabel();

private Color blue = Color.BLUE.darker();
private Color red = Color.RED.darker();
private Color yellow = Color.YELLOW.darker();
private Color green = Color.GREEN.darker();


public SimonShape ()
{

    JLabel label = new JLabel();

    setSize(800,800);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setVisible(true);


    simon.setFocusable(true);
    simon.setOpaque(true);
    simon.addKeyListener(this);
    this.add(simon);
    setVisible(true);
    simon.requestFocusInWindow();


    label.setFocusable(true);
    label.setOpaque(true);
    label.addKeyListener(this);
    this.add(label);
    setVisible(true);
    label.requestFocusInWindow();


    randomColorChange();
}


private void randomColorChange()
{

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Level " + level);
        random = (int) (Math.random() * 4);
        comp.add(random);
        //light up sequence
        for (int i = 0; i < level; i++)
        {

            if (comp.get(i) == 0)   simon.colorChange(0);
            else if (comp.get(i) == 1)  simon.colorChange(1);
            else if (comp.get(i) == 2)  simon.colorChange(2);
            else if (comp.get(i) == 3)  simon.colorChange(3);
        }
}
```

SimonPanel.java (Holds the shape)

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.geom.Arc2D;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class SimonPanel extends JPanel{

private int width = 500;
private int height = 500;
private int x = 150;
private int y = 150;
private int TURN = 45;


private SimonListener listener;
private Timer timer;

private Color blue = Color.BLUE.darker();
private Color red = Color.RED.darker();
private Color yellow = Color.YELLOW.darker();
private Color green = Color.GREEN.darker();

// speed of the light up sequence
  private int lightUpSpd = 500;

// chooses random color based on numbers 0-3
  private int random;

// keeps track of user inputs 
  private int compCounter = 0;


public SimonPanel()
{   

}

public void colorChange(int color)
{

    if (color == 0)
    {
        //lightUp();
        green.brighter();
        repaint();
        listener = new SimonListener(this,green);
        timer = new Timer(lightUpSpd,listener);
        System.out.println("green");
        timer.start();

    }
    else if (color == 1)
    {
        red.brighter();
        repaint();
        listener = new SimonListener(this,red);
        timer = new Timer(lightUpSpd,listener);
        System.out.println("red");
        timer.start();
    }
    else if (color == 2)
    {
        blue.brighter();
        repaint();
        listener = new SimonListener(this,blue);
        timer = new Timer(lightUpSpd,listener);
        System.out.println("blue");
        timer.start();
    }
    else if (color == 3)
    {
        yellow.brighter();
        this.repaint();
        listener = new SimonListener(this,yellow);
        timer = new Timer(lightUpSpd,listener);
        System.out.println("yellow");
        timer.start();
    }
}


public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

    // Blue Section
    g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(1.0f));
    g2.setPaint(blue);
    g2.fill(new Arc2D.Double(x,y,width,height,180+TURN,90,Arc2D.PIE));

    // Red Section
    g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2.0f));
    g2.setPaint(red);
    g2.fill(new Arc2D.Double(x,y,width,height,90+TURN,90,Arc2D.PIE));

    // Yellow Section
    g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2.0f));
    g2.setPaint(yellow);
    g2.fill(new Arc2D.Double(x,y,width,height,-90+TURN,90,Arc2D.PIE));

    // Green Section
    g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2.0f));
    g2.setPaint(green);
    g2.fill(new Arc2D.Double(x,y,width,height,360+TURN,90,Arc2D.PIE));

}
}
```

Test Class

```
public class SimonTest  {

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    new SimonShape();
}

  }
```

SimonListener.java

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;


public class SimonListener implements ActionListener {


private JPanel panel;
private Color color;



public SimonListener(JPanel panel, Color color)
{
    this.panel = panel;
    this.color = color;
}


public void setColor(Color newColor)
{
    color = newColor;
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 

{
    color.brighter();
    System.out.println("Called");
    panel.repaint();

    ((Timer) e.getSource()).stop();
}

}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you mean when you say it is not working?  Are you getting an error or is it producing unexpected results?

Comment: There's coding missing; `randomColorChange`, `SimonListener`; Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your "main" problem "seems" to the fact that you are not assiging the changes to the color objects back to anything;

```
green.brighter();
```

From the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#brighter())

> Creates a **new** Color that is a brighter version of this Color.

You should be doing something more like

```
green = green.brighter();
```

I would also consider having a "base" color from which you can derive bright/darker colors from, but that's me

Comment: That was very careless of me. How did I not notice that before? Thank you.

Comment: Just out of curiosity why the quotation marks around main?

Comment: @igknighton There could be other errors, but there is missing code.